# How to use System Icons in an Xcode AppleScript application?

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave, applescript-objc

Is there any way to use the System icons, located in:/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/
without having to add them to the Resource folder of my project in an application with AppleSript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use the POSIX path.  If you are using **display dialog**, AppleScript in Xcode s a bit fussy, so you will need to explicitly coerce it:

```
display dialog "hello" with icon ("/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericQuestionMarkIcon.icns" as POSIX file)
```

if you are using **NSAlert**, the icon property needs to be an image, so you can get one from the path, for example:

```
set myAlert to current application's NSAlert's alloc's init()
set myAlert's messageText to "hello"
set myAlert's icon to current application's NSImage's alloc's initByReferencingFile:"/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericQuestionMarkIcon.icns"
myAlert's runModal()
```

For other objects that use an **NSImage**, you can get an image from the path in the same way, and set the object's image by using the relevant property or setter method:

```
set yourImageView's image to current application's NSImage's alloc's initByReferencingFile:"/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericQuestionMarkIcon.icns"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @red_menace, but I did not know how to ask the right question, sorry, I would like to use the icons in an ImageView.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an ImageView - see **NSImage** for other attributes and methods that can be used with the icon (or other) image.